# How to extract request parameter from $request?

Tags: regex, nginx, nginx-config

I want to extract request parameter( reqId ) value from $request in http block using regex and `map`
Can you please help me resolving it ?

Sample URL :

```
test-registration.com/emp/reg?reqId=939393&usrName=Jimmy
```

I am not sure what would be the regular expression in this case but possible 
solution would be like

```
http {
    map $request $requestId {
      "regular expression"  $reqId;
    }
}
```

If there is any other solution to resolve this issue, please let me know.
I thought I can use $arg_reqId but I am not sure whether I can use it in http block or not.

EDITED:
After extracting the id I want to apply sha-256 hashing on it and put it back to $request.
So new value of $request should be like :

> test-registration.com/emp/reg?reqId=$#&$#&yewywjd3&usrName=Jimmy

Thanks

Comment: why not just use `$arg_reqid`, Not sure if it is case-sensitive so try `$arg_reqId` if the lower case doesn't work

Comment: @TarunLalwani Do i need to use $arg_reqId inside <% %> ?

Comment: Your question doesn't specify how and where you want you want to use this value. Once you clarify that it would be easier to comment

Comment: @TarunLalwani I want to hash that id and put it back to $request

Comment: Please update your question with one such example. Specify what type of hashing and and what will the updated request look like

Comment: You will need to use openresty or nginx with lua embedded and then do this conversion

Answer (score 0):

You could try this pattern: `reqId=([^&]+)`

Explanation:

`reqId=` - match `reqId=` literally

`(...)` - capturing group

`[^&]+` - match one or more characters other than `&`

Required value wll be stored in first capturing group.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/uUMd3F/1)

Comment: Thanks @Michal.. So you mean map block should be like 
map $request $requestId {
      reqId=([^&]+)  $reqId;
    } ?

Answer (score 0):

What about this map block:

```
http {
    map $request $requestId {
      "~/emp/reg\?reqId=(?<reqId>[0-9]+)"  /doSomething/$reqId;
    }
}
```